# Omit, skip redis cache store, if it not available

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redis, redis-cache

I use redis-store as cache store for Rails

```
config.cache_store = :redis_store
```

When the redis-request fails (no connection during restart of redis, redis down, timeout, etc) the whole application fails.
Is there an option to just skip redis and acting like if there were no such key?

Thanks and regards, Phil

**Edit:**
Further discussion can happen here:
https://github.com/jodosha/redis-store/issues/175

Question is answered for me. (Only possible with patching, see issue 150)

Answer (score 0):

Just put a timeout and try/catch on your redis request. If it fails, act as if the key doesn't exist and go on.

Comment: Yes, something like this. But how can I do it, when I'm using the Rails.cache ?
I do not handle the redis-request directly by myself.